# Given a 3D box, a ray direction and a point on a face, find the other point on the box intersected by the ray

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 3D program which only renders the rear faces of a box. Given a ray intersection with one of the rear faces (point **A**), I want to obtain the point **B** on the box which would be the point of intersection with the front face. I understand that I can move in the negative direction of the ray from point **A** some distance **D** to arrive at point **B**. Is that the best approach, and if so how do I calculate that distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: box]

Imagine that you have your box like this, placed on the x y z axis. (Note this is a left-handed system.) Suppose that the point on the rear corresponding to the ray is (x0,y0,z0) and the ray has direction (a,b,c). Suppose the box has dimensions length (l), width (w), and height (h). We want to find the point (not labeled) on the front of the box such that the ray originated.

[image]

You want to scale the direction of the ray so that it can basically be superimposed on the box so we can use the pythagorean theorem. Focus on the x direction, which spans the length of the box. Divide l by a to find r, the scaling factor, that you will need to multiply the components of the ray to find the scaled ray "superimposed" on the box. From here, you can directly use the pythagorean theorem to get

$$\begin{split}d&=\sqrt{a^2r^2+b^2r^2+c^2r^2}\\
&=r\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\\
&=\frac l a\sqrt{a^2 + b^2+c^2}\end{split}$$

**Note**: the letter "l" looks like a 1, but it's not. Or, going step by step, look at the above picture and see that the base is $base=\sqrt{a^2r^2+b^2r^2}$. Now there is one more step, we take the base and factor in the height of the ray.

[image]

And we find that the distance is $distance=\sqrt{c^2r^2+\left(\sqrt{a^2r^2+b^2r^2}\right)^2}$ as before. To find the point, simply move a distance d in the opposite direction of the ray. This is done by finding the unit vector in the direction opposite the ray and adding that times the distance to the point you were at, effectively moving you the desired distance in 3-D space.

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\\z_0\end{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}*\frac l a\sqrt{a^2 + b^2+c^2}\\
=\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\\z_0\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}*\frac l a\\
=\begin{pmatrix}x_0-l\\y_0-b*\frac l a\\z_0-c*\frac l a\end{pmatrix}$$

So you see we didn't actually have to do all that work, the simplified form shows that it is attained by simply finding the scaling factor **along the length of the box**, and then moving in the direction of the ray by the scaling factor from the original point. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. Can this method be applied to a ray that passes through a plane other than the front plane (ie. any perpendicular plane)?

Comment: The answer is for opposite faces, but I think you can adjust the method to work for any perpendicular face. Eg. suppose that the origin of the ray is on the xz plane and the rear is still the rear. Then the scaling factor is $s=\frac {y_0}{b}$ and the point is given by $$\begin{pmatrix}x_0-a*\frac {y_0}{b}\\y_0-b*\frac {y_0}{b}\\z_0-c*\frac {y_0}{b}\end{pmatrix}$$ Something similar can be done for other faces, and you can make modifications if the box is not at the origin.

Comment: I'll accept the answer because you did a good job answering my question as written, and my question wasn't specific enough, but I'm looking for a generalized solution to the problem. I believe there should be a branchless solution.